# dijit.Tree from XML

Tags: ajax, tree, hierarchy, dojo

I've been trying to get a Tree to work using my xml. But i'm like stuck without any clue as how to move ahead. I've tried quite a few things, which i've tried and would mention here.

Background: I've been trying to create a tree from XML which looks like:

```
<root>
  <hierlabel>A_Level0</hierlabel>
      <hierlabel>A_Level1</hierlabel>
            <hierlabel>A_Level2</hierlabel>
  <hierlabel>B_Level0</hierlabel>
       <hierlabel>B_Level1</hierlabel>
   :
   :
</root> 

So i expect a tree like :
   |-A_Level0
   |  |- A_Level1
   |      |- A_Level2
   |-B_Level0
      |- B_Level1
```

Problem: In the examples that i see, the 'ForestStoreModel' that is being constructed requires a 'childrenAttrs' property. But in this case there is no such field which defines the parent/child relationship, instead its just the '**hierarchy**' which defines such a relation.

Code:

```
var store = new dojox.data.XmlStore({
                jsId:'mystore',
                url:'http://localhost/someplace/somewhere?getxml=true
            });

            var treeModel = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({
                store: store,
                rootItem:'hierlabel',
                label:'hierlabel',
                query: {
                },
                rootLabel: "MyLabels",
                deep:'true',
            });

            new dijit.Tree({
                model: treeModel

            },  "treeOne");
```

I've even tried overriding the getChildren function but no luck! If thats the only correct way, more pointers on that would help!

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer to my question. Adding it here, might help others looking for it!

Following is a very good example of the same.

http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/data/demos/demo_MultiStores.html

Thanks!